# Исчезают данные из БД при лимите памяти

Tags: yii, php, limit

В цикле обрабатывается массив, спарсенный перед этим из xml. Данные либо обновляются, либо добавляются в БД. Так вот, если случается лимит памяти, то все данные, которые были затронуты перед этим - удаляются. Из трех таблиц. Почему такое случается? Yii 1.1.16

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что они именно исчезают, а не записываются в конце скрипта, который не всегда дорабатывает свое?
2. Может ли быть такое, что в начале скрипта у вас открывается транзакция в БД?

Comment: 1. Данные уже могут быть добавлены ранее, однако все равно исчезают.
2. Вряд ли она сама открывается. И если оборвать скрипт из PMA, то данные останутся. Исчезают именно затронутые данные, и именно при лимите памяти.

Comment: код в студию.

Comment: А вы как-то проверяете запрос на удачную обработку? errors? affected_rows? insert_id?
И да, используете ли транзакции? Какая БД? Какая схема БД?

Comment: Вдобавок подскажите, как сделать лучше :)
https://github.com/iljas-galiev/catalog/blob/master/YmlModule.php